# StormPath Spring Boot Integration - getting Invalid CORS request error

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors, stormpath

Trying to integrate the StormPath with Spring Boot receiving multiple errors. Following here is the application setup.

Using stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter version 1.2.1.

```
1) application.properties contains only stormpath id, secret and href as follows,

stormpath.client.apiKey.id = <id>
stormpath.client.apiKey.secret = <secret>
stormpath.application.href = <href>

2) SpringSecurityWebAppConfig.Java (Override spring security)

@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityWebAppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.apply(stormpath());
    }
}

When application is run,
------------------------
1) http://localhost:8080/register renders register screen. 

2) http://localhost:8080/login (GET) throws error "Unable to invoke StormPath controller: Resolved account store cannot be an Organization".

3) http://localhost:8080/login (POST)  (from PostMan) throws error "Invalid CORS request".
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your problem #2 we released the [SDK v1.2.2](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/milestone/65?closed=1) and fixed the issue you're facing now. When organizations and/or groups were mapped to an application this problem occurred. Updating the library version will allow you to render the `login` page.

As for #3 you have two options either to disable the CORS filter `stormpath.web.cors.enabled = false` or add the PostMap `origin` header to the list of allowed `originUris` i.e. `stormpath.web.cors.allowed.originUris = <origin-header-value>`.

In case you want to dig in more about CORS you might be interested in checking the blog [Tips and Tricks for AngularJS and Spring Boot with Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/blog/angularjs-spring-boot-tips#easy-cors) article from one of Stormpath Evangelists.

Hope this helps,

José Luis

Full disclosure: I am one of Stormpath's Engineers.

Comment: #2 got resolved by upgrading to SDK v1.2.2 however #3 still seeing error.  Added stormpath.web.cors.enabled = false in the application.properties file now login (POST) is throwing "403, Forbidden, No Message Available" error. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Faizal, sorry to hear about the 403 response, since you're using PostMan the response is caused by stored cookies in it, when the `LoginController` sees login attempt on an already authenticated request (stored cookies) will reject the request with 403. Can u try to clean the cookies and/or use another client like `curl` to confirm that is the issue you are facing? Thanks

Comment: with curl I am able to hit the post url however not with PostMan (cleared the cookies)

Comment: Hi @Faizal, happy to see that it's working in `curl`, regarding you deleting the POSTMan cookies, how did you do that? I'm assuming you're using the chrome extension, where by default don't show any cookies being sent/received, but when I enabled the POSTMan interceptor at the top, I could see the cookies being sent, not an easy way to remove them manually. However, the way I made it work is calling the `/logout` endpoint. That will clear the cookies for sure, then you can retry the `/login` again. HTH.

Comment: Glad to hear @Faizal.